# Citing an image

Tags: citing

I want to cite the image of the link: https://www.pinterest.com/pin/607211962229526005/?d=t&mt=signupOrPersonalizedLogin

I tried as follows:

```
Melbourne tram map 2020, digital photograph, accessed 11 September 2020, <https://www.pinterest.com/pin/607211962229526005/?d=t&mt=signupOrPersonalizedLogin>.
```

Have I correctly cited it?

Comment: That entirely depends on the citation standards for your publication. You should consult the style guide for citations of online resources. I would say that it's probably better to cite the original source, http://ontheworldmap.com/australia/city/melbourne/melbourne-tram-map.html and not a Pinterest link to it.

Comment: I completely agree with Don Hosek, whether that is an appropriate bibliography entry is completely up to the style guide (and other rules and regulations) you have to follow for your work. That question is independent of how you write your document, so not really a (La)TeX problem. It should probably be asked at https://academia.stackexchange.com/, but they probably can't say more than: check what your style guide says.

Comment: Apart from that I would avoid citing images from pinterest. Instead try to find the original source of the work and cite that. For one my browser (Firefox) refused to open the link for some obscure reason. And more importantly, if you cite the original source you have a chance to find the correct metadata (author, publishing date, title, ...) and (quite important) license information.

Comment: Note that the copyright notice at the bottom left of the image says 2015, so the map may be outdated now. The current maps available at https://www.ptv.vic.gov.au/more/maps/ all look quite different.